Should I canonicalize image URLs for SEO purposes?
At the moment, you can load picture from my website using a path such as:

/supplements/vitamin-d3-14016/images/label.webp

I am working to add avif support, i.e. The same picture can now be loaded using:

/supplements/vitamin-d3-14016/images/label.webp
/supplements/vitamin-d3-14016/images/label.avif

At the moment, I am also returning a Link header with the image, such as:
</supplements/vitamin-d3-14016/images/label.webp>; rel="canonical"

My question is: As I am adopting a new image format, should I canonicalize it to the new image format or should I have it fallback to webp to avoid the same image being indexed twice?

NO, there is no such provision. Canonical tag is used to prevent content duplication unfortunately for media there is no such provision.
You can visit this YouTube video from Google Search Central office hours.

At (55:04), you can find the relevant information in the video.

You can read more about canonical tag here.
I hope this is helpful.
If you want to provide different format and size for your images then use "srcset" attribute in "" tag. You can read more about it here.
